# Is my 2-gang switch box over-full with 5 cables?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, junction-box

I am installing a dimmer, and I thought there were a lot of wires in this box. It looks like there are 5 cables into a 2-gang box.

I tried to draw a little diagram and attach a photo to make it clearer. Is this over-full, or normal?  Was thinking the dimmer will throw off more heat and this may be unsafe. All the neutrals are wired together,  as are the hots, but since the backside of the dimmer is so much larger, there is no room for this all to fit. Wires are 12 AWG.

My questions:

1. Is this normal or overloaded?
2. Can I remove some of the inputs and how?
3. Should I just make a new box next to it and install the dimmer there?

I am a little new at the electrical thing, but I've installed a bunch of lighting/switches successfully before.

Thanks for any help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are these wires 12AWG or 14AWG?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: I don't mind ESL, but -1 for not bothering with basics like using the shift key, leaving off basic words, resetting your cookies for no reason (why?)  and using SE like a forum instead of what it is.  If you want us to make an effort, meet us halfway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wires and devices need 18x2.25 = 40.5 cubic inches.

What you have there is a 4x4 square metal box.  If it's 1-1/2" deep it'll be 21 cubic inches.  Otherwise I'd expect to see a cubic inch number stamped onto it. There's also a 2-gang mud ring of, well, it sure ain't 19.5 cubic inches!

Note that the mud ring does not come all the way out to the wall surface.  It is quite shy of that.  This is improper installation, so you need to replace the mud ring *anyway*.  So replace the mud ring with one of the correct height, even if it doesn't have enough cubic inches.  We have one more trick.

Lastly, you can obtain a **surface conduit starter box** e.g. Legrand Wiremold.  That will provide some additional cubic inches (depending on its height).

If you get the statutorially needed cubic inches, you should have enough room for the dimmers.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the surface (front) box with 1 1/4" surface box, which gave me exactly what you said, more cubic inches.  Dimmer fit and added a switch plate space to deal with the slight 1/4" protrusion from the new surface box.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a 4 inch square box, probably the 1.5 inch deep 21 cubic inch flavor, with a 2-device mud ring (an additional 5.5 to 8.8 cubic inches depending if it's 1/2, 5/8 or 3/4 deep - it's 1/2, at a guess)

Count 1 for grounds, 1 for clamps, 4 for 2 devices, and 10 wires per your diagram (but I see red wires so I suspect some of those cables have 3 wires (+ground) not 2 wires (+ground.) That would make the required space larger yet.

For 12 gauge wire you need 2.25 cubic inches for each wire "count" (hot/neutral/switched - all grounds only count as 1, each "yoke" device counts as 2) so you need 16 * 2.25 = 36 cubic inches and this box does not have that even with the most generous cover assumption.

So, it's overfull. Whoever put it in either got away with something or didn't pull a permit, most likely - I don't think this is an area where standards have changed much over time, so I doubt it's grandfathered.

If you are contemplating ripping the wall open to add another box, and there is enough room, you could use a 4-11/16 square box, 2-1/8" deep, for 42 cubic inches (before any cover space) rather than play games with two boxes (where the wires between boxes still add up and can make you overfull.)

Comment: I see red wires, so apparently the switched-hot of the lights is on /3 cables OP is not mentioning.  That explains the statement 'all the blacks are together, all the whites are together' which would obviously be wrong otherwise.  Hence I expect there to be 2 more wires.